# dealing with systemjs load time and sequence - there must be a better way

Tags: angularjs, systemjs

I have a situation using `system.js` with an `angular` application where I need to be able to include specific `System.import(f)` statements on a per-page basis, but it was imperative that they all be included **before** angular finishes bootstrapping and loading up its module.

I spent a long time on this problem and eventually this is the workaround I devised;

in my **config.js**, I am doing this...

#### config.js

```
// .... configuration ... //

Promise.all([
    System.import('jquery'),
    System.import('angular'),
    System.import('angular.ng'),
    System.import('bootstrap')
]).then(function() {
    $(document).on('angular', function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['module-name']); $('body').removeClass('cloak');
    });
});
```

Then I have a `css` class named `.cloak`. I tried `ng-cloak` but found it wasn't doing the job (I suspect because I'm deferring the angular bootstrapping)

```
.cloak { visibility: hidden; }
```

then on my individual page, I use this sort of code to shoe-horn my page-specific imports and finalize the process.

```
<!-- Load SystemJS -->
<script src="assets/js/system.js"></script>
<script src="config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('app/main').then(function (e) {
        Promise.all([
            System.import('app/controllers/index'),
            System.import('app/controllers/read'),
            System.import('app/controllers/edit/article'),
            System.import('scripts/lib/init')
        ]).then(function (m) {
            $(document).trigger('angular');
        });
    });
</script>
```

So that's the basic idea; I don't allow `angular` to finish wiring up its module until everything has been imported through `system.js`. At present, this *seems to* work fine.

My problem is that I'm not a very good programmer, nor am I very clever. This seems like an extremely standard, normal problem that comes with the way `system.js` is designed and it occurs to me that there **has** to be a better, built in solution that I'm missing or haven't found.

Has anyone else dealt with this before that can offer some advice?

The reason I need to defer the module wiring is because I've got various angular controllers and models and such and I don't want them *all* to load on every page. (I mean, trimming down the scripts to only the ones needed at the moment is one of the points of a module loader, aside dependency resolution).

Trying to use the `ng-app` directive was constantly causing trouble - as angular would try to load before everything was finished and loaded in, so it had trouble finding things like certain controllers and the like on certain pages.

The biggest reason I need an alternative is that this method doesn't work well for minifying typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extremely standard issue with ng-cloak in general. Perhaps a better way has come around, but pretty much since I started working with angular I've just defined ng-cloak in the header of my index.html file like this:

```
<style>
[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

and added class="ng-cloak" to the body tag of my page. It works great and when Angular finishes loading it's internal ng-cloak styles effectively overwrite mine.

It seems like moving the inline script basically as is, to an external file, would still allow it to run exactly as you have it and then minification and such would be fine.

It also sounds like you're not creating a SPA here, since if I understand you correctly, you're calling config.jss from each page. You may want to reconsider that and go with a SPA. You will likely end up loading everything up front, but you'll load it all only once.

Comment: Wow, this worked great! Thanks! And I understand what you mean about the SPA, but I'm not very interested in one. I'd rather keep the pages separate. So far this trick of yours works wonderfully.